# calculating limits using Maclaurin series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

$h(x)$ is a continuous function in the section $I$, $0 \in I$, $h(x)$ has a derivative at $x=0$ and $h(0)=0, h(x)>-1 (0 \ne x \in I)$. $f(x) = (\frac{(1+h(x))^{1/h(x)}}{e})^{1/x}$, for every $0 \ne x \in I$. I need to prove that $$ \lim_{x\to0}f(x)= \sqrt{\frac{1}{e^{h'(0)}}}=e^{-\frac{h'(0)}{2}}$$.

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0}{e^{ln{f(x)}}}$$ hence I need to find $\lim_{x \to 0}{ln f(x)}$.
$$\lim_{x \to 0}{ln f(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0}{ln (\frac{(1+h(x))^{1/h(x)}}{e})^{1/x}}=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{ln(\frac{(1+h(x))^{1/h(x)}}{e})}{x}}=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{ln((1+h(x))^{1/h(x)}-ln (e)}{x}}=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\frac{1}{h(x)}ln(1+h(x))-1}{x}}$$
I then expressed $h(x)$ using Maclaurin series, with Lagrange form of the remainder, to express $h(x)$ and $ln (1+h(x))$ I get: $$h(x)=h'(\xi)\cdot x$$ and $$ln (1+h(x))=\frac{h'(\xi)}{1+h(x)}=\frac{h'(\xi)\cdot x}{1+h'(\xi)\cdot x}$$ and getting back to the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\frac{1}{h'(\xi)\cdot x}\frac{h'(\xi)\cdot x}{1+h'(\xi)\cdot x})-1}{x}}=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{-h'(\xi)\cdot x}{x+x^2\cdot h'(\xi))}}$$ and using l'hopital's rule I get $$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{-h'(\xi)\cdot x}{x+x^2\cdot h'(\xi))}}=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{-h'(\xi)}{1+2x\cdot h'(\xi))}}$$ because $\xi\to 0$ when $x\to0$ the \limit I finally get is $$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{-h'(\xi)}{1+2x\cdot h'(\xi)}} =\frac{-h'(0)}{1+2\cdot 0 \cdot h'(0))}=-h'(0)\Longrightarrow \lim_{x\to0}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{e^{h'(0)}}$$ I tried working around this so many times but I don't know how I get the root part of the wanted result.

---

### EDIT

I tried a different approach $$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{ln(1+h(x))-h(x)}{x\cdot h(x)}}$$

using the Maclaurin series:
$$h(x) = h(0) + h'(0)x + \frac{h''(0)x^2}{2} + R_2$$
$$h(x) = h(0) + h'(0)x + R_1$$
$$ln (1 + h(x)) = h'(0)x + \frac{h''(0)x^2 - (h'(0))^2 x^2}{2} + S_2$$
($R_2$, $S_2$ are the remainders of order 2 and $R_1$ is the remainder of order 1). then 
$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{ln(1+h(x))-h(x)}{x\cdot h(x)}}=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{h'(0)x + \frac{h''(0)x^2 - (h'(0))^2 x^2}{2} + S_2-h(0) - h'(0)x - \frac{h''(0)x^2}{2} - R_2}{x(h(0) + h'(0)x + R_1)}}=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{-\frac{(h'(0))^2 x^2}{2}+S_2 - R_2}{x^2h'(0)+xR_1}}=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{-\frac{(h'(0))^2}{2}+\frac{S_2}{x^2} - \frac{R_2}{x^2}}{h'(0)+\frac{R_1}{x}}}$$
now because $$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{S_2}{x^2}}=0, \lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{R_2}{x^2}}=0, \lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{R_1}{x}}=0$$
the limit is
$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{-\frac{(h'(0))^2}{2}+\frac{S_2}{x^2} - \frac{R_2}{x^2}}{h'(0)+\frac{R_1}{x}}}=\frac{-\frac{(h'(0))^2}{2}}{h'(0)}=-\frac{h'(0)}{2}$$ hence $$ \lim_{x\to0}f(x)= \sqrt{\frac{1}{e^{h'(0)}}}=e^{-\frac{h'(0)}{2}}$$
but I don't know if I'm allowed to use 2 different order of Maclaurin series

Comment: You are given that $h'(0)$ exists. At no other point do you even know that $h$ is differentiable, much less having higher derivatives. You can't even use the Lagrange form of the remainder, because that requires $h$ to be continuously differentiable on an interval. (And, by the way, in the Lagrange form, the value of $\xi$ varies with $x$, and also with the function being expanded, so you get a different "$\xi$" from $\ln(1+h(x))$ than you get from $h(x)$ itself. You should not use the exact same symbol for both.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can come straight from the definition of the derivative and the limit: Since $h(0) = 0$ and letting $k = h'(0)$, we have that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x| < \delta$, then $\left|\frac{h(x) - 0}x - k\right| < \epsilon$, so $$kx - \epsilon|x| < h(x) < kx + \epsilon|x|$$

That is all you need to know to take your limit.

Comment: I know it can be done in different ways, but I was asked to use Maclaurin series

Comment: You have only 1 derivative at a single point. That makes it a Maclaurin (actually "Taylor") *polynomial*, not a Maclaurin *series*.  And what is the best Maclaurin polynomial you can do in this case? $$h(x) = h(0) + h'(0)x + h_1(x)= 0 + kx + h_1(x)$$ for some error term $h_1$. And what is the best possible bound on $h_1$? For any $\epsilon$, there is a $\delta$ such that when $|x| < \delta$, then $|h_1(x)| < \epsilon |x|$. And how do you prove that? See my post.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how is this helping in proving the $$\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{e^{h'(0)}}}$$

Comment: Pull the other leg, it has bells on. You already essentially did that calculation in the edit to your question, except you used a form unjustified by the information given. I've showed you the form that can be justifed by the information given. The rest of the calculation is the same (except not so messy with unnecessary terms).

Comment: I still don't understand how I can use this. going back to my calculations I get $$h(x)=h'(0)x + R_1$$ and $$ln(1+h(x)) = h'(0)x + S_1$$
so the limit is $$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{h'(0)x + R_1 - h'(0)x - S_1}{x(h'(0) + S_1)}} $$ and from here I'm clueless as I always get that the numerator becomes zero

Comment: I gave you a better estimate than just "$R_1$" and "$S_1$". Why don't you try using it?

Comment: because I don't see how a better estimate can help me show that $$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{ln (1+h(x)) - h(x)}{xh(x)}} = -\frac{h'(0)}{2}$$

Comment: $\ln (1 + x) = x - \frac {x^2}2 + O(x^3)$. Plug $h(x) = kx + h_1$ into that (where $k = h'(0)$ and $h_1 < \epsilon|x|$) and reduce to $-\frac k2 +...$. The order of $x^3$ stuff will have a leftover multiplier of $x$ and go to zero. The remaining terms can be bounded by a fixed multiple of $\epsilon$ for small enough $x$. But $\epsilon$ is arbitrary.